# Display Great Plains invoice report from website

Tags: report, dynamics-gp

We're trying to display invoice reports from great plains through our website. We're looking to have gp store the invoice report pdf once they are created and emailed. We are using gp 2010 and are currently using the built in feature that allows us to send an email to the customer containg the invoice as a pdf.

I'm on step one here, being that I'm trying to get a hold of the GP invoice reports. It appears that they may be created in GP on the fly and are not saved to any folder that I can access. Does anyone know where these invoice files are stored? I would think it has to store them somewhere on the client machine or somewhere else in order for the email to attach the file.

Here is a similar related post on the Dynamics forum, the answer here is concerning. They told him to use a dexterity customization to accomplish the saving of the invoice pdf.

http://community.dynamics.com/gp/f/32/t/106071.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The GP invoices are generated on the fly and not stored permanently on disk.

All of the data you need to generate the invoice is contained in the company database in Dynamics GP. My advice to you would be to create your own invoice in a technology compatible with your website such as SSRS or ASP.NET, etc. Then you can generate an invoice on the fly from the data in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bryan. Management decided that we wanted to keep these invoice PDFs in the status they where the day they where printed. That can be a bit wasteful when it comes to storage of the files, but we do have to store things that will change data wise, such as payment terms, customer documents, etc. So they decided they wanted the PDFs as is and not to create an on the fly report.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we never found where GP is storing the invoice PDFs that it emails, and the decision was made that they didn't want to create the reports on the fly. They wanted to store the original report from GP. So that left us with 2 choices.

1. Have GP save all of the invoices in a batch to a single word file. This option is built into GP, when user goes to print the invoices (or email them) there is also a check box that allows them to save the invoices of the entire batch to a single word file. We then would have to separate this file into each separate invoice document using c# or something.
2. Use Exchange web services to access the emails and download the attachments to a folder. This requires that we BCC every email with the account we will get to using the exchange web services. This is the option we ended up going with.